# Updating Parent Entity doesn't Update Child Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Whether attaching parent entity to the context again and updating it should update the child entity? Am i missing something?

Or should I necessarily write the updating EF logic (in DAL) for the child entity?

This is my sample code model:

```
ChildEntity entityChild;
if (ParentEntity.ChildEntity.SingleOrDefault() != null)
    entityChild = ParentEntity.ChildEntity.SingleOrDefault();
else
{
    entityChild = new ChildEntity();
    ParentEntity.ChildEntity.Add(entityChild);
}

entityChild.ColumnA= txtA.Text;
entityChild.ColumnB= txtB.Text;

// Send entityParent for update
_objParent.Update(entityParent)
```

_objParent.Update() code:

```
context.vouchers.Attach(entityParent);
ObjectStateEntry objectState = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityParent);
objectState.ChangeState(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE (Parent Loading Code Sample)**

```
    public ParentEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            ParentEntity _entity = context.ParentEntity
                .Include("ChildEntity")
                .Where(e => e.parent_id == id);

            return (ParentEntity)_entity.SingleOrDefault()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding or updating the parent object? If you're updating the object, please show us how you're loading it.

Comment: see the already provided _objParent.Update() code above. 1) Attaching the entity, 2) get the ObjectStateEntry, 3) Modifying the Sate, 4) Saving the change to the context.

Comment: How do you load the parent?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. Please see above I have added the parent loading code.

Comment: `ChangeState` only changes the state of `entityParent`, not its child objects. You'll have to change the state of child objects too.

Comment: @Ali.NET: No prob :) Check my answer below and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF only track changes from the point where it gets to know about the object. The most simple way to work with updates in EF is to load the existing object from the DB, update it and then save it back. In this case it means that you should load the `ParentEntity` object from the DB.

The other approach is to use `Attach` as you do. In that case you should *first* call attach the *unchanged* `ParentEntity` and then call `ParentEntity.ChildEntity.Add(entityChild)`.

Another alternative is to explicitly add the new `ChildEntity` directly to the DbContext, then you could simply set the foreign key value of the `ChildEntity` to the key value of the `ParentEntity` to make them connected.

Comment: I got your point. The only matter not clear in my mind is to identify whether to add the ChildEntity or modify? As the ParentEntity gets changes (add/modify ChildEntity) in the UI layer I have to devise some technique to identify the change mode (Add/Modify). Would it be appropriate to identify the chage mode using ModifiedBy and EnteredBy properties of the ChildEntity. (i.e. If ModifiedBy is null, means this should be an Add operation)

Comment: The easiest way to work with change tracking is to load both the `ParentEntity` and all related `ChildEntities` (use `Include(p => ChildEntities)` in the query) and then updated/add the children before doing `SaveChanges`. Saving without loading in EF is often harder than expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should load and update your entities inside the using statement - this way all the changes will be tracked by the Entity Framework:

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
    // load and update entities
    // ....

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**UPDATE** - This is just an example, I'll keep it simple. I would create a service where I'd put my logic - something like this:

```
public class ParentService
{
    // other service methods here

    protected DBEntities CreateContext()
    {
        return new DBEntities();
    }

    public ParentEntity Update(int id, string columnA, string columnB)
    {
        ParentEntity _entity = null;

        using (var context = CreateContext())
        {
            bool isNew = false;

            _entity = context.ParentEntity
                .Include("ChildEntity")
                .SingleOrDefault(e => e.parent_id == id);

            ChildEntity entityChild = ParentEntity.ChildEntity.SingleOrDefault();

            if(entityChild == null)
            {
                entityChild = new ChildEntity();
                isNew = true;
            }

            entityChild.ColumnA = columnA;
            entityChild.ColumnB = columnB;

            if(isNew)
            {
                ParentEntity.ChildEntity.Add(entityChild);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return _entity;
    }
}
```

In the UI code:

```
string id = .....;
string columnA= txtA.Text;
strign columnB = txtB.Text;

var service = new ParentService();
ParentEntity parent = service.Update(id, columnA, columnB);
```

Comment: But the problem is, the entities get pass across the application layers (DAL, BAL, UI), hence become detached from the context. So your provided sample would require extensive changes in that regard. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ali.NET: updated my answer. My advice: create a services layer that will contain all logic and data access. The UI will access then the service, so this way you don't mix UI with the rest.

Comment: I had this logic in my mind. But this way the application will hit the server twice to update entities. Performance issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to say - you are already accessing the database 2 times... The first time to load the entities, the second to update them. What's the difference?

Comment: I meant, in your update service method you are going to hit the server, first, for ** getting the child entity ** and then for Context.SaveChanges. That additional hit I wanted to avoid.

Comment: That's why I just added 1) "whether to add or modify the child" functionality and 2) explicitly adding/modifying the child to the context, in my above (actual question's) code to resolve the issue.